# Windows 7: is there a system log before crash?

Tags: windows-7, crash, logging

Does Windows 7 log any files about core temperatures etc which I could access later if a crash occurred?

This would help me greatly in finding out why my computer suddenly shuts off and won't boot any more. I've unplugged lots of things - 3x RAM, 1 HDD, CD/DVD - and have managed to boot the computer now. However it would have been more helpful if Windows 7 had logged some information I am not aware of yet.

If Windows 7 does log such real time information, where can I access it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for specifically hardware status (temperatures, voltages), no.  Out of the box, Windows 7 has no interface to access this sort of information.

Windows DOES try to record information about running processes and take a memory dump at a crash if at all possible - the easiest way to get to this info in Windows 7 is to launch the Reliability Monitor (it's buried in Control Panel somewhere, I forget actually, but you should just be able to type it into the Start Menu).

Comment: There is no record kept, but WMI should be able to access the information, as long as the chipset drivers choose to make that information available via WMI.

Comment: @Joey - Right, I was speaking in the context of saving logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect that a device is causing your system to crash, try stress-testing your hardware with benchmark or test programs to see what happens (you can individually test the CPU, GPU, or HDD). At the same time you could monitor the system temperatures - I don't know any specific programs for doing this but you can search Google for something useful.

Comment: yeah but those tests will take lots of time and may actually cause damage to my system, also, i dont think it is possible to test my PSU, i think the problem arises from that in my situation...